# Определение цвета пикселя

Tags: javascript

Как скриптом вывести цвет пикселя, при правом клике мыше по экрану?

Answer (score 3):

Можно отрендерить изображение страницы в Canvas (например, с помощью библиотеки [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)), после чего получить цвет любого пикселя не составит труда. Недостаток: не будет работать в браузерах, не поддерживающих Canvas (IE 8 и ниже).